# Bluebird throwing exception at source code

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using bluebirdjs for nodejs application. It throws an exception from its source code.

Line : `try {throw new Error(); } catch (e) {ret.lastLineError = e;}`

Path : bluebird/js/release/util.js

Line : 374

This exception seems unnecessary to me. It only throws exception. Is it rational to delete this line?

Same code also exists inside async.js at line 3.

Comment: The `catch` block has a side effect so you can't delete it without reasonably expecting some functionality to change.

Comment: But try block will always throw exception. It is someting like if(true){}. It should be like "ret.lastLineError = new Error();". But this method is looking like a bug or forgotten when publishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IE an `Error` object will not have a `.stack` property unless it goes a  through try catch. The `.stack` property is needed to see which line and file the code is in.

`ret.lastLineError = new Error()` would therefore only work in firefox and chrome

Comment: So it will also get the stack from the `throw` and not the `new Error`, wouldn't it?